# I'm haveing issue logging to WordPress dashboard using mobile phone

Tags: php, wordpress, function

The error message is referring to this code in theme functions
Here is the code `td_util::set_check_installed_plugins();`

```
    } else {
        echo '
        <!--
            Error: ' . $buffer . ' (rara-error)
        -->
       ';
```

Comment: What have you tried? Since when did this happen? What is in the `if` statement above.

Comment: You should also share with us the error in question (if there are personal data in it, just shadow it, for example with "#")

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I noticed it first time 4 days ago. For now I can still access my dashboard from my computer and through WordPress.com website log in page. Bet each time I type mysite.com/wp-admin from any mobile browser, it will open an error warning. I'm pasting the error message here.

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/u0592416/simitru.com/wp-content/themes/Newspaper/includes/wp_booster/td_util.php:1313) in /var/www/u0592416/simitru.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1251

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/u0592416/simitru.com/wp-content/themes/Newspaper/includes/wp_booster/td_util.php:1313) in /var/www/u0592416/simitru.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1254